# netplan wifi with multiple AP

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, netplan

I have two AP and want to connect one of them and use the second as a fallback.
But currently, netplan connects to one of them and if it switched off, only manual switch `wpa_cli -i wlp2s0 select_network network_id` works. Or restart, and the host will connect to the second AP as the first not available at the moment. But when the first AP starts in won't reconnect back automatically.

So, how can I fix the lock on first AP and change AP priorities?

```
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        ap1:
          password: pass1
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.43.2/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 192.168.43.1]
      optional: true
      access-points:
        ap2:
          password: pass2
```

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: Nope. In examples I can find how to set eth0 more preferred than Wi-Fi, but not how to change AP's priority on the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Configure netplan to use the NetworkManager backend, not the default networkd backend which does not have support for this.